# atom expand selection from all cursors

Tags: atom-editor

I have begun using atom full time and loving it for the most part.
One thing I miss is the ability to expand alt selection up or down from all cursors.

- Does this feature currently exist?
- If not does anyone have any idea if a package might be capable of implementing such a feature?

Let me explain a bit more:

In Sublime Text 2/3 we could have multiple cursors. Anything action performed would happen on all cursors. Such as <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> would select text from all cursors right one character. I had mapped <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> to the sublime `select_lines` command for forward and reverse respectively. These actions would also be applied to all cursors. So, if I had a cursor on line 10 and 20 and I used the down combo I would have a cursor on lines 10,11 and 20,21. In atom, using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> will `expandDown` to the next line down. **But**, this only happens from the last placed cursor.

Please note that I already use [multi-cursor](https://atom.io/packages/multi-cursor) which does not provide the desired functionality. It is also limited to expanding the selection from the last created cursor though it does help with other things.

Comment: Is [this](https://atom.io/packages/multi-cursor) what you're looking for?

Comment: @jcbermu Thanks, but I already use it. I updated the question to explain a bit.